# Can you target a specific option in a jump menu and replace the text with JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I need to target 'Ehime' in the following list and replace with 'Ehime - Not Available'.

```
<div class="control"> <span>
                   <select name="state" size="1" id="state_field" class="select_large valid left" 
                        <option value="">Please select your state</option>
                        <optgroup class="JP" data-iso="JP" label="???country.jp???">
                                    <option value="CH">Chiba</option>
                                    <option value="EH">Ehime</option>
                                    <option value="FS">Fukushima</option>
                                    <option value="GI">Gifu</option>
                                    <option value="GM">Gumma</option>

                        </optgroup>
                    </select>
              </span> 
    </div>
```

I've been experimenting with the following JS but can't find a way of pinpointing a specific option.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#state option').text('Ehime - Not available);
});
```

I'd appreciate some tips.

Thanks,

Adam

http://jsfiddle.net/ebf5zwq5/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of issues. Firstly there are several syntax errors in your HTML:

```
<div class="control"> 
    <span>
        <select name="state" size="1" id="state_field" class="select_large valid left">
            <option value="">Please select your state</option>
            <optgroup class="JP" data-iso="JP" label="???country.jp???">
                <option value="CH">Chiba</option>
                <option value="EH">Ehime</option>
                <option value="FS">Fukushima</option>
                <option value="GI">Gifu</option>
                <option value="GM">Gumma</option>
            </optgroup>
        </select>
    </span> 
</div>
```

Then in your jQuery code you are trying to select the `#state` element yet the id of the select is `#state_field`. You were also missing a closing quote on the text value. You can use the attribute selector to find a specific element, in this case by the `value` attribute:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#state_field option[value="EH"]').text('Ehime - Not available').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ebf5zwq5/2/)

Note that I have also disabled that `option`, otherwise it would still be selectable.

Comment: Fantastic. Didn't know you could target a value like that. Many thanks